# json_encode() adding slashes to my REST API

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, rest

I am trying to serve my application JSON data. And for the most part it works. But posing some challenges.
So I am pulling data from my database, it has no slashes on the content.

Let me show you some code.
This is my SendResponse function() (shortened)

```
function send_response($res) {
        if($res) {
            $res['_total'] = count($res);
            if('success' === $res['status']) {
                $res['code'] = 200;
            }
            
            header_remove();
            header("Cache-Control: no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900");
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            header('Status: '.$res['code']);

            echo json_encode($res,   JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
        } 
    }
```

When I request data from my API, I get the response that looks like this.
The issue with this, is it makes it challenging on the Javascript side to access the data, because half of it is showing as actual JSON, but parts aren't (IE: the items array element).

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Those are backslashes. And *doubly* encoded JSON. So, just don't convert string values and arrays twice.

Comment: thats ok. your string has double quotes in it

Comment: @mario, i'm only encoding it one time, as you can see on my code above.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, but I cannot access, json[0].items[0].id... it won't work.

Comment: Yes, we can only see the part of the code where you only encode it once. The resulting output tells a different story though.

Comment: @mario Aside from the extra 'slashes'. Do you know why my "items", is loaded as a string, and not return to an array?

Comment: From the output I can only surmise that "items" was json_encoded already before it reached the code section you disclosed here.

Comment: Hey, hard for me to show everything, but promise there was no other encoding. But I did solve this by, before sending data to browser, I looped through the results, because the ITEMS element, was just a string, so I applied json encoding now, and it's working. I appreciate your time. Thank you.